# Series coefficient not working for abstract powers

Tags: evaluation, series-expansion, coefficients

I'm trying to extract coefficients of some complicated polynomials.

If I try to write
`SeriesCoefficient[1/(x-1)^4,{x,0,m}]`, this works fine, everything as expected.

If I then try to some arbitrary exponents to $x$, it doesn't evaluate:
`SeriesCoefficient[x^n/(x-1)^4,{x,0,m}]`
I tried adding the assumptions that $n$ is an integer, and still no luck.

What's the quick fix here if I want to evaluate the above and more slightly more complicated expressions like:

```
SeriesCoefficient[(n^2 x^(3 + n) + x^(4 + 2 n)/((1 + n)(-1 + x)^4)), {x, 0, m}]
```

as a function of $m,n$.